# How to detect privacy permission changes (Camera access for example)

Tags: ios, avfoundation, uiimagepickercontroller, eventkit, photokit

We've all been there. You want to take photos within your app, or access photos, microphone, contacts, etc... But first iOS must prompt the user for permission. In many cases the user will deny access.

If your app detects that the user has denied access, you can navigate the user to the App's privacy settings with this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Handy. However....

I've noticed that if you do convince the user to toggle the switch to on, that the app does not detect the changes.

Consider this code. The user is immediately prompted for permission to access the camera (this only shows the first time that app is run). Suppose the user denied permission. Next they decide that they did want to enable camera access after all. No problem. The user taps on the button which brings up the privacy panel. The user changes the switch to allow access. Then the user switches back to the app. The block fires for UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification which reads the permission again. However it does not reflect the user's changes (still reads as Denied).

If the app is purged from memory and run again, it will properly read the state.

Not all permissions behave this way. For instance CoreLocation seems to detect the user's changes. I've also found a way to detect changes for Notifications. But for Contacts, Calendars, Camera, Microphone, Core Motion (and more) the changes are not detected until the app is terminated and run again.

Any ideas?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@import AVFoundation;

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        [self printPermission];
    }];

    [AVCaptureDevice requestAccessForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo completionHandler:^(BOOL granted) {
        [self printPermission];
    }];

}


-(void)printPermission{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        AVAuthorizationStatus status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined){
            NSLog(@"VWWPermissionStatusNotDetermined");
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        } else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){
            NSLog(@"VWWPermissionStatusAuthorized");
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        } else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
            NSLog(@"VWWPermissionStatusDenied");
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } else if(status == AVAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
            NSLog(@"VWWPermissionStatusRestricted");
            self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        }
    });
}

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
}

@end
```

Comment: "But for Contacts, Calendars, Camera, Microphone, Core Motion (and more) the changes are not detected until the app is terminated and run again." But in my experience, if the user changes the permission while the app is running, the app _is_ terminated.

Comment: I have one device where that app is always terminated. Also in the simulators. I have a few other devices where it most certainly is not terminated.

Comment: Okay, but I find in situations where the app is not terminated, testing for authorization in e.g. `viewDidAppear` works correctly. See for example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch19p725calendar/ch32p986calendar/ViewController.swift In my tests, that works correctly if we send the user off to the settings app and the user grants permission.

Comment: If you think you've worked out an answer, then instead of modifying your question, your should _answer_ your own question. You can even accept your own answer (after a while)! That is the best way to help others who may encounter this issue.

Comment: Thx, will do. I wasn't sure if that would be perceived as greedy or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this turned out to be a bug related to iOS 9b1.

Permission detection works fine on iOS 8.

I did learn that you need to check the permission on the main queue. If you do that, it will reflect updates.

Comment: Has it been ever been patched since then? iOS 9.2 seems to have the issue.

Comment: No I don't think so. I was writing a permission prompting framework when I ran into this issue. I used said framework this week and the problem persists (crash the debugger). I'm running iOS 9.2. No crash when running in standalone though.

Comment: Debugger does not crash neither. I just catches some sort of "shadow" exception. But you can continue with the execution. Checking on main thread did not resolve the issue for me.

Comment: Haha, the issue has been solved: when I debug it wont terminate the app. When I run standalone it terminates the app (at least).

Comment: When I say crash, I mean it causes the debugger to crash if you launch into the Privacy settings pane and toggle a setting. IIRC not all permission changes cause the debugger to crash but either photos or camera did for me this week. in any case it works fine in the wild.